# Which JavaScript file hid my element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to figure out which file (and which line in that file) modified my DOM?  I have numerous plugins and .js files.  I can't figure out which file is hiding an element.  The class names and id of the element are very generic so it's hard to pin down where it is.  Is there a way to see in Chrome's console? Thanks!

Comment: If you're using chrome, you may be able to right click on the element in the inspector and break on attribute modification.

Comment: @AnthonyTJRivas: Good call. Knew there was a duplicate somewhere.